# Работа с классами динамически загруженной dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Первичная задача:  проверять наличие dll, чтобы при ее отсутствии программа не вырубалась, а продолжала дальше работать, пусть и потеряв часть функциональности.
На мой взгляд, это проще всего делать, динамически загружая dll. Но встает вопрос: как тогда перегружать функции классов, которые в ней лежат? А это просто необходимо.
И как создавать объекты объявленных там классов?

Comment: Это какое-то извращение. Не делайте так.

Comment: @nitrocaster, ну почему же? Необязательные UI возможности *Windows API* последних версий, поддержка множества версий DirectX/OpenGL с выбором той, что установлена у пользователя – да мало ли где есть необходимость условной загрузки библиотек? В программу встраивается базовый функционал, замещаемый по возможности таковым из более продвинутой библиотеки.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте реализацию функциональности по умолчанию. Заведите указатели на функции, инициализируйте их функциями по умолчанию. Попытайтесь загрузить dll, если загрузилось, замените адреса на функции из dll.

Если хотите, инкапсулируйте всё механику в отдельный класс.

(Это для C++, с C# аналогично.)

Answer (score 2):

Например вот так:

```
//Подгружаем .dll
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("my.dll");
//Находим класс который хотим использовать
Type typePlugin = asm.GetType("PluginClass");
//достаём конструктор
ConstructorInfo ctor = typePlugin.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
//Создаём обьект
object objPlugin = ctor.Invoke(null);
//вызваем метод обьекта
typePlugin.GetMethod("myMethod").Invoke(objPlugin, null);
```

Всё это дело лежит в `System.Reflection`